# Eliminating vurnabilities in the Spring SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm testing the Spring SpEL and I thinking if it is possible to somehow limit what kind of SpEL query can be provided, to avoid some unwanted code injection? I just want to get values from some object, so is it possible to block other types of operations? I can't find such functionality in the Spring documentation.

For instance, I just want to allow to check if the value from the *test* object equals XYZ.

```
Test test = new Test("XYZ", 999);
ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression("value eq 'XYZ'");

System.out.println(expression.getValue(new StandardEvaluationContext(test)));
```

However, I would like to limit which expressions are valid. I don't what to evaluate expressions which allow to execute some code, for instance:

```
Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression("''.getClass().forName('java.lang.Runtime').getMethods()[6]");
```

Comment: See if `SimpleEvaluationContext` can help you somehow. This was designed exactly for security reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@ArtemBilan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan) mentioned in the comment, the solution to limit the SpEL language syntax and eliminate unwanted code execution is to use the `SimpleEvaluationContext` class, for instance:

```
SimpleEvaluationContext context = SimpleEvaluationContext.forReadOnlyDataBinding()
.withInstanceMethods()
.withRootObject(test)
.build();
```

Comment: Nice! You can accept your own answer.